# Custom selection of items for jQuery-UI:Selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a main div, with sub divs inside:

```
<div id="selectable">
  <div class="item text"></div>
  <div class="item image"></div>
  <div class="item text"></div>
</div>
```

When I add the jQuery of:

```
$('#selectable').selectable();
```

All of the divs inside are thus selectable.

Is there a way to remove the selectable class on the div that has a class with 'image'?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want custom selection that is your syntax streight from the UI api

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({ filter: 'div:not(.image)' });
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/bBBER/8/

You can be even more spesific

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({ filter: 'div.item:not(.image)' });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bBBER/9/

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$( '#selectable > div:not(.image)' ).selectable ();
```

This selector will select all child `div`s of `#selectable` that [don't have](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) the `image` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not` selector to exclude elements with `image` class

```
$('#selectable').children("div:not(.image)").selectable();
```

Comment: I guess it's because this selects _way_ more than intended; namely (almost) all children of `.image` and (almost) all children of elements that are also selected.

Comment: Ahh..., should be `.children` not `.find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on each element and then avoid those with class image. Like :

```
$('#selectable').each(function(div) {
 if (!$(this).hasClass('image'))
   {
     $(this).selectable();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
  $('div.image').removeClass('selectable');
```

Answer (score -1):

I imagine not as the parent div is selectable and thus everything contained will inherently be selected as they are children of that div. You could simply take some elements out of the selectable div?